# Converting month flags into dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table format;

```
tripID  
departureDate (date)  
availableJan (bit)  
availableFeb (bit)  
availableMar (bit)  
availableApr (bit)  
availableMay (bit)  
availableJun (bit)  
availableJul (bit)     
availableAug (bit)    
availableSep (bit)  
availableOct (bit)  
availableNov (bit)  
availableDec (bit)
```

Trips will have **either** a selection of any of the 'available' flags **or** a departure date.

What I'm trying to make is a database function which will convert the flags into a usable date based on the current date.

So if a trip has a null departure date, and is available Aug,Sep,Oct then  given the current date is 8th May 2016. I would like a function to return the date 1st August 2016.

The logic here is that the function returns the first day of the next available month from the current date.

More examples, with e.g. today date of 06/06/2016;

Month flags as true: Jan, Feb, Mar
Expected output: 1st Jan 2017

Month flags as true: Jan, Jun
Expected output: 1st Jun 2016

Month flags as true: Jun, Jul, Aug, Dec
Expected output: 1st Jun 2016

I have gone round in circles trying big if statements, temp tables but I wondered if there was a more clever way of achieving this that doesn't kill the processor.

Any help much appreciated,

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you think of writing a bunch of UNION statements like that, think *fold*.  What you want is the minimum available date for a trip.  So, first make dates, then put them in a column, then select the minimum one.  The whole shebang can be one in one `select` statement.

First, make yourself a static table of 12 rows holding the integers 1-12.  Let's call it `Months`.  Then

```
with start as (
    select dt = dateadd( YEAR,
                         datediff(YEAR, '20000101', getdate()),
                         '20000101' )
)
select TripId, min(departure) as Departure
    select TripID
         , case month
           when 1 then case availableJan 
                       when 1 then dateadd(MONTH,month,start.dt) end
           when 2 then case availableFeb 
                       when 1 then dateadd(MONTH,month,start.dt) end
           --- 10 more times --
           end as departure
    from itinerary cross join Months
) as M
where departure >= getdate()
group by TripID
```

This technique is known as *folding* and might be thought of as the opposite of *pivoting* (i.e., arranging rows as columns).  It's usually much more efficient for the DBMS to execute than a sequence of UNIONS because -- even though there's a lot of SQL -- there's only one mention of the table.  The results can be produced by making a single pass over the data; the server's only problem is what to do with each row.  It's also less wordy and, once you get used to it, an easy idiom to recognize.

Answer (score 0):

First available 1st of month starting today

```
with start as (
  select dt = dateadd(YEAR,datediff(YEAR,'20000101',getdate()),'20000101')
)
select tripID 
 , firstDate = (
   select min(d) 
   from (
      select d = start.dt where availableJan = 1
      union all
      select d = dateadd(MONTH,1,start.dt) where availableFeb = 1
      union all
      select d = dateadd(MONTH,2,start.dt) where availableMar = 1
      -- ...
   )
   where d >= getdate() )
from mytable
join start;
```

Comment: Thanks serg, I am getting error: The multi-part identifier "start.dt" could not be bound. 

Were you meaning to join the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Serg's answer (thanks!), I managed to achieve the desired result with the following;

```
DECLARE @firstDayOfCurrentYear date = dateadd(YEAR,datediff(YEAR,'20000101',getdate()),'20000101')
DECLARE @firstOfCurrenyMonth date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(GETDATE())-1),GETDATE()),101)

SELECT 
    itinerary.*,            
    COALESCE 
    (
        departureDate,
        (
            SELECT MIN(d) FROM 
            (
                SELECT @firstDayOfCurrentYear                   AS d WHERE availableJan = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableFeb = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,2,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableMar = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,3,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableApr = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,4,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableMay = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,5,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableJun = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,6,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableJul = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,7,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableAug = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,8,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableSep = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,9,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)   AS d WHERE availableOct = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,10,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableNov = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,11,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableDec = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,12,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableJan = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,13,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableFeb = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,14,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableMar = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,15,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableApr = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,16,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableMay = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,17,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableJun = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,18,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableJul = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,19,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableAug = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,20,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableSep = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,21,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableOct = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,22,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableNov = 1 UNION ALL
                SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,23,@firstDayOfCurrentYear)  AS d WHERE availableDec = 1
            ) AS dateTable where d >= @firstOfCurrenyMonth
        )
    ) AS inclusiveDepartureDate
FROM 
    itinerary
```

This account for when the month is part way through the year, so the next departure date is in the following year (i.e. I union 24 rows, not just 12).

I use COALESCE to only execute this operation when the normal departureDate is null.